# Hide typescript files in ido-find-file when javascript files are present in folder Emacs

Tags: emacs, typescript

Whenever I use `ido-find-buffer` in Emacs I most of the time get the processed javascript files as first option, while I'd much rather get typescript files first.

Then again, I do not want to *always* hide javascript files, I guess only when using typescript as well.

Perhaps the best is to have typescript put the javascript files in another folder itself.

Is there a good solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can have Typescript store the compiled files in another folder using the compiler option

```
"outDir": "dist"
```

Or whatever folder you want them to output into

Answer (score 0):

I just noticed it is possible to define it in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w --outDir build",        // <--- here
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "start": "concurrent \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" "
  },
...
```

It gets written to a `build` directory and thus is not causing issues anymore.